# how to traverse a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes, tree-traversal

I have a root Node of a binary tree and I want to traverse all nodes and make a key for each node.but the function stops whenever it finds the first node.

This is my function:

```java
    public void createKey(Node root,String s,HashMap<String,String> map){
        if(root==null)
            return;
        if(root.right==null&&node.left==null) {
            hashMap.put(node.symbol, s);
        }
        createKey(node.left, s + "0",hashMap);
        createKey(node.right, s + "1",hashMap);
    }
```

when I print the hashmap I get this output:
z : 000

I expect an output like this:
z : 000
a : 001
b : 010
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

You put values to the map only for leaf nodes in your tree. You need to change your code to the following:

```
public void createKey(Node root,String s,HashMap<String,String> hashMap){
    if(root==null)
        return;
    hashMap.put(root.symbol, s);
    createKey(root.left, s + "0",hashMap);
    createKey(root.right, s + "1",hashMap);
}
```

Comment: I want to put values for only leaf nodes.My problem is that the function stops when it finds the first leaf node.I tried your code but still just goes to the deepest left node and stops

Comment: Have you used debugger to check that your tree has correct structure?

Comment: yes.I create the tree before the method and sure it is correct but the method does't work

Comment: Then just try to debug your code to check what is actually going on there

Comment: I debugged it and explained the problem briefly.it just goes deep and stops

Comment: Your traversal code seems to be fine. Can you show the code that prints the content of the hashmap ?